# Translation of Dirichlet polynomial

Tags: polynomials, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

Assume $P(s)$ is a Dirichlet polynomial, say
\begin{equation}
P(s)=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{a(n)}{n^s}.
\end{equation}

**Is $P(1-s)$ a Dirichlet polynomial too?** I.e., is there a way to write
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{a(n)}{n^{1-s}}=\sum_{n=1}^M\frac{b(n)}{n^s}
\end{equation}
with certain $b(n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if $P$ is constant ($a(n) = 0$ for $n > 1$). If $P$ is a Dirichlet polynomial (or a Dirichlet series that converges somewhere), then we have

$$\lim_{\operatorname{Re} s \to +\infty} c^{-s}P(s) = 0$$

for every $c > 1$.

But if $P$ is a non-constant Dirichlet polynomial,

$$P(s) = \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{a(n)}{n^s}$$

with $N > 1$ and $a(N) \neq 0$, then

$$\lim_{\operatorname{Re} s \to +\infty} N^{-s}P(1-s) = \frac{a(N)}{N} \neq 0.$$

Comment: Thanks alot for the fast and competent answer! But what about Dirichlet series? If $P(s)$ is a Dirichlet series that is absolutely convergent in the whole complex plane, say, is there a way to write $P(1-s)$ as a Dirichlet series, too?

Comment: Editing a comment doesn't send a new ping, so I haven't seen the edit until now. If you make such an addition to a comment, it is therefore safer to post a new comment. Again that is only possible if $P$ is constant. For a Dirichlet series $P(s) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a(n)\cdot n^{-s}$ that converges somewhere, we have $\lim\limits_{\operatorname{Re} s \to +\infty} P(s) = a(1)$, uniformly in $\operatorname{Im} s$. So if $P$ converges (absolutely) on the entire plane, and $P(1-s)$ has a convergent Dirichlet series representation on some half-plane $\operatorname{Re} s > \alpha$, then

Comment: $$\lim_{\operatorname{Re} s \to -\infty} P(s) = \lim_{\operatorname{Re} s \to +\infty} P(1-s)$$ exists (uniformly in $\operatorname{Im} s$). So there are $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $M > 0$ with $\lvert P(s)\rvert < M$ for $\operatorname{Re} s \leqslant c$. By the absolute convergence of $P$, we have $\lvert P(s)\rvert \leqslant M' := \sum \lvert a(n)\rvert n^{-c}$ for $\operatorname{Re} s \geqslant c$. Thus $P$ is a bounded entire function, hence constant.

Comment: Thanks again! That solved that matter. As you seem to know the ropes and as the issues are somewhat related, I would be glad if you could finally just take a glance on this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244965/identity-between-absolutely-convergent-generalized-dirichlet-series question of mine.

Comment: I already have it open in a tab XD But it's nothing I can answer off the top of my head. I need to think about it when I'm away from the computer (and then it's still quite possible that I draw a blank).

Comment: All right and thanks for trying!